# Bootstrap button block not working on iphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is how i am trying to insert a button in my div using bootstrap btn-block

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4   w-50">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="decreaseTheQuantity()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">{{quantity}}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="increaseTheQuantity()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8  w-50">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"   (click)="submitProductToACart()">Hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome dev tool it will be shown like this.

[image: Button in DEV tool]

On phone (Safari and chrome) it is like this

[image: real iphone layout]

Apart from Bootstraps classes i am not using any css classes. 
I want to align it to right as shown in the first picture.
I am not sure how can i fix this or recreate this locally.
Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks

**** Update *****

In DEV Tools i have tried different resolutions there i can see that it is properly aligned.

[image]

Comment: You are probably not testing against the correct dimensions in your chrome dev tools. Note that once you go into responsive mode, there's a drop-down menu in the top left. From there, you can select x device and get the proper dimension of said device. You can also google the dimension of other devices and add them etc. What you then need to do is to work with media queries in CSS so that your styles are applied to the dimensions you wanna work with. Example: `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) { //style goes here }`

Comment: @Martin thanks for your reply.I have updated my post. I have selected different resolutions in DEV tool. My question is should not the problem occur there as well ?

Comment: If there are issues within x dimensions, it should occure in the dev tools as well, yes (given you are testing the proper dimensions to replicate the error). It's all about fiddling with the dimensions and see if things are the way you want them to be. If not, work from there. @lesnar